# Index out of range error, when it isnt

Tags: c#, arrays

I have the following method:

```
private void DetermineIfWagerIsValid(CouponViewModel result, Bet bet, string wagerType, int selectionCount)
{
    if (bet.Wagers[0].WagerType == wagerType) //error here
    {
        if (bet.Selections.Count != selectionCount)
        {
            bet.BetStatus = BetStatus.FilledInAndInvalid;
        }
    }
}
```

Simple enough, but I am getting an intermittent 'Index out of range' error, when the index doesn't appear to be out of range:

[image: Out of range]

Here's the StackTrace:

> at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException()    at
>   System.Collections.Generic.List`1.get_Item(Int32 index)    at
>   System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1.get_Item(Int32 index)
>   at
>   Arkle.CouponProcessing.Scan.LonglistDecoder_994550.DetermineIfWagerIsValid(CouponViewModel
>   result, Bet bet, String wagerType, Int32 selectionCount) in
>   c:\code\Arkle\Arkle\Arkle.CouponProcessing\Scan\LonglistDecoder_994550.cs:line
>   117    at
>   Arkle.CouponProcessing.Scan.LonglistDecoder_994550.DetermineIfBetIsValid(CouponViewModel
>   result) in
>   c:\code\Arkle\Arkle\Arkle.CouponProcessing\Scan\LonglistDecoder_994550.cs:line
>   107    at Arkle.CouponProcessing.Scan.LonglistDecoder_994550.Decode()
>   in
>   c:\code\Arkle\Arkle\Arkle.CouponProcessing\Scan\LonglistDecoder_994550.cs:line
>   62    at ArkleWPF.UI.SlipScanning.CouponTools.DecodeCoupon(Image img,
>   OMRForm omrForm1, CouponDecoder decoder, CouponPrintingInformation
>   viewSettings, String slipBarcode, DecodeStatus status) in
>   C:\code\Arkle\Arkle\ArkleWPF\UI\SlipScanning\CouponTools.vb:line 215
>   at ArkleWPF.UI.SlipScanning.CouponTools.ProcessForm(OMRForm omrForm1,
>   DecodeStatus status, CouponPrintingInformation viewSettings, Boolean
>   alwaysLotto) in
>   C:\code\Arkle\Arkle\ArkleWPF\UI\SlipScanning\CouponTools.vb:line 89
>   at ArkleWPF.UI.SlipScanning.CouponTools._Closure$__1._Lambda$__1() in
>   C:\code\Arkle\Arkle\ArkleWPF\UI\SlipScanning\CouponTools.vb:line 27
>   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
>   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)    at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)    at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)    at
>   System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()

It's not happening every time, it's more like every second or third time and it's driving me crazy! Any ideas?

Comment: I'm pretty certain exceptions are always right.

Comment: @GrantThomas Completely agree, but check out the screenshot and you will see why I'm confused!

Comment: Is `WagerType` a property? How is it implemented? Does it happen to access a collection? I am guessing that the error isn’ generated by the access to `Wagers[0]` but something else on that line.

Comment: do you use multithreading in some place to access Wagers ?

Comment: @JMK Unfortunately all questions supported by images are a little vague for me in working hours unless they only supplement the question itself, as my work network blocks imgur.

Comment: What does the stack trace say? Is it possible that `WagerType` does some indexed access in its `get`?

Comment: Wagers is an observable collection, yes this is running on a thread. Could this be a race condition issue?

Comment: What I am thinking is that exception is coming from inside Wagers[0]. Can you debug code inside, in its getter?

Comment: @FaisalHafeez Good point, I will debug the code inside the getter, thanks

Comment: Look for stack trace (click `View Detail`) or just catch an exception and print a stack trace. It's not clear where exactly exception is thrown.

Comment: What is the .StackTrace?

Comment: @GrantThomas I understand, the image was just a screenshot showing the code with the exception, and a screentip showing the Wagers

Comment: @MarcGravell Added the StackTrace

Answer (score 1):

```
 System.Collections.Generic.List1.get_Item(Int32 index) at
 System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection1.get_Item(Int32 index)
```

The requested index does not exist in the list lookup.  `Wagers` is an array but `WagerType` does not have the requested index.  The `exception` is being raised from within the list's `get` statement.